# Android links not working in a webview

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink

Basically I'm parsing the HTML of a web page and then loading it into a webview via a string using "loadData". My problem is this stops my links working, the webview doesn't know the current URL of the page so when a link is clicked rather than loading http://myurl.com/page.html it tries to load http://page.html which clearly doesn't load.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem without editing the HTML pages?

Answer (score 0):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)